# Does Journey Builder's Salesforce Data detect rollup changes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, roll-up-summary

The title is pretty straight forward. Do you know if Marketing Cloud's Journey builder's **Salesforce Data Entry Source detects roll-up changes as an update**, or does it ignore it and not consider it an update of the record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roll-up-Summary field changes cause the record to update (save) in Salesforce, as opposed to e.g. formula fields. So a Roll-up-Summary field change gets synced to Marketing Cloud as any normal field.
For reference, [see order of execution info in Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save procedure.
>   If the parent record is updated, and a grandparent record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the grandparent record. Grandparent record goes through save procedure.